# Expand background photo entire width of card

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I can't seem to eliminate the white space of the background photo.  Below is all of the .css styling i've tried:

```
    .prflBg {
    ion-card-content{
    background-image: url('../assets/img/headerBg.png');
    background-size: 320px 158px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    margin-left: -10px !important;
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: You probably want to remove `background-repeat` and change `background-size` to `cover`. Without a [mcve] you make it impossible for anyone to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "background-size" property is what determines how large your image will be. It's hard to know where things are going wrong without knowing the size of your background image, or the container you are trying to put it in.

However the background-size property is pretty standard to work with. The first number determines the width of the image, the second determines the height. There are also ["word" choices](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) you can use that do various things.

In your case I would recommend using "background-size:cover" as this is what the cover value does according to w3Schools:

> Cover will resize the background image to cover the entire container,
>   even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the
>   edges

Comment: Please note w3schools is not a reliable source of information. It's a private website trying to capitalize advertising space displayed around web related documentation while using a name creating the confusion they are somehow affiliated with W3C, which they are not. Also, their docs are lacking and sometimes even wrong. If you want reliable docs, use either MDN (joint effort of Mozilla, Google, Microsoft and many others) or W3C (official web documentation - a bit too technical at times, but complete).